# Best practice to implement cache

Tags: database, caching

I have to implement caching for a function that processes strings of varying lenghts (a couple of bytes up to a few kilobytes). My intention is to use a database for this - basically one big table with input and output columns and an index on the input column. The cache would try to find the string in the input column and get the output column - probably one of the simplest database applications imaginable.

What database would be best for this application? A fully-featured database like mysql or a simple one like sqlite3? Or is there even a better way by not using a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document-stores are **made** for this. I highly recommend Redis for this specific problem. It is a "key-value" store, meaning it does not have relations, it does not have schemas, all it does is map keys to values. Which sounds like just what you need.

Alternatives are MongoDB and CouchDB. Look around and see what suites you best. My recommendation stays with Redis though.

Reading: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Answer (score 1):

Joe has some good recommendations for data stores that are commonly use for caching. I would say Redis, Couchbase (not CouchDB though - it goes to disk fairly frequently/not that fast from my experience) and just plain Memcached.

MongoDB can be used for caching, but I don't think it's quite as tuned for pure caching like something like Redis is. Mongo can hit the disk quite a bit.

Also I highly recommend using time to live (TTL) as your main caching strategy. Just give a value some time to expire and then re-populate it later. It is a very hard problem to pro-actively find all instances of some data in a cache and refresh it.